# PHP class not working

Tags: php

It makes an error, all I want it to do is return $fcEnable as the result from the database within this class.......

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in
>   /home/site/page.php

```
$VisitorIP = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$IPCheckQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blah` WHERE `ip` = '" . $VisitorIP . "'");
$IPCheckR = mysql_fetch_array($IPCheckQ);
class GeoIP extends Page {
 public $fcEnable = $IPCheckR['x'];
}
```

Comment: Why did you not include the line number with the error message?

Comment: You can't assign variable to `public $fcEnable` as a value. Use constructor or some other method to set its value.

Comment: how about showing all the code? this is a mess.. there's just a 'random' class sitting there under your `$IPCheckR`

Comment: @MikeB Obviously it's the line within the class.

Comment: Attribute declarations in a class definition can only be constant values, not expressions. - See [Initializing PHP class property declarations with simple expressions yields syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702863/initializing-php-class-property-declarations-with-simple-expressions-yields-synta) (And array dereferences are just that.)

Comment: @Latox Not obvious. Assumptions can lead to more bugs and I found it very odd that the line-number was selectively removed from the error message. OP made no attempt to explain, diagnose, or research the error (which is the first thing you always do via line number) and jumped straight into 'make this work'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign another variable to a var inside the class.

```
class GeoIP extends Page 
{
 public $fcEnable;

 function __construct($fcEnable = null)
 {
        $this->fcEnable = $fcEnable
 }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

`$fcEnable` is within the scope of `GeoIP`. The code outside the scope of the class needs to be executed inside the class, or like this:

```
class GeoIP extends Page
{
    public $fcEnable;

    public function __construct( $ipcheck )
    {
         $this->fcEnable = $ipcheck['x'];
    }
}

$VisitorIP = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$IPCheckQ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `blah` WHERE `ip` = '" . $VisitorIP . "'");
$IPCheckR = mysql_fetch_array($IPCheckQ);
$gip = new GeoIP( $IPCheckR );
```