# Is it possible to create an associative array which holds instances of a custom class?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initializing PHP class property declarations with simple expressions yields syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702863/initializing-php-class-property-declarations-with-simple-expressions-yields-synt)

Is it possible to create an associative array and parse instances of a custom class as values?

Something like:

```
 private static $contentTypeList = array(
    "News" => new ContentType("News", "news.php", "News"),
    "Termine" => new ContentType("Termine", "termine.php", "Termine"),
    "Zeitplan" => new ContentType("Zeitplan", "zeitplan.php", "Zeitplan"),
    "Fotos" => new ContentType("Fotos", "fotos.php", "Fotos"),
    "Anfahrt" => new ContentType("Anfahrt", "anfahrt.php", "Anfahrt"),
    "Guestbook" => new ContentType("Guestbook", "guestbook.php", "G&auml;stebuch")
    );
```

Trying this I'm getting an error like "unexpected keyword NEW".

Do I use the wrong syntax or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, but not when declaring the property outside of a function body.

Add it into any function, for example:

```
class SomeClass {
    private static $contentTypeList = array();
    public static function init() {
      self::$contentTypeList = array(
        "News" => new ContentType("News", "news.php", "News"),
        "Termine" => new ContentType("Termine", "termine.php", "Termine"),
        "Zeitplan" => new ContentType("Zeitplan", "zeitplan.php", "Zeitplan"),
        "Fotos" => new ContentType("Fotos", "fotos.php", "Fotos"),
        "Anfahrt" => new ContentType("Anfahrt", "anfahrt.php", "Anfahrt"),
        "Guestbook" => new ContentType("Guestbook", "guestbook.php", "G&auml;stebuch")
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: That it's `private` doesn't seem relevant. And really your solution is sub-optimal: `init` is not `static` and you're requiring two-phase initialisation.

Comment: `variable` is slightly misleading: Its about properties.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: should be fixed now

Comment: @KingCrunch: should be fixed now .

Comment: @KingCrunch: Properties are variables.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: that's true, too. But, to be accurate, `method` is just a function, too :)

Comment: @Martin: I prefer "member variable" and "member function", because I come from C++.

Comment: So I will not use static functions but create an instance and fill the array in the constructor. Thank you!