# PHP string concatenation within class definition

Tags: php, string, class, concatenation, php-5.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initializing PHP class property declarations with simple expressions yields syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702863/initializing-php-class-property-declarations-with-simple-expressions-yields-synt)

Is it possible to achieve the following in `PHP 5.2.17` ?

```
$basePath = '/final';

class Foo {
    public $data = $basePath . '/data';
}
```

Comment: Nope. No expressions in property declarations. Use le constructor.

Comment: @mario Thanks, haven't found that post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default values for properties must be *constant* in the source, e.g. strings and array literals. No expressions.

Use the `__construct()` method for anything more complicated.