# PHP set class property to a std object in class defination

Tags: oop, class, std, php

Is there a way in PHP the class definition to have a property set to a STD object with set properties?

I was thinking you can type cast but its not allowed for properties in the class definition.

```
//example.
class Foo{
   private static $Obj = (object) ['bizz', 'bazz'];
}
```

which will trigger this error:

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(object)' (object) (T_OBJECT_CAST)`

Comment: Why do you think that anything in the [existing answers to that same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2702875/367456) (but not limited to PHP 5.4) should be different in that PHP version? Which part of the PHP Changelog made you believe that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assign non-constant values to class properties during declaration. From http://php.net/language.oop5.properties

> ...initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

You will need to use a class method to initialise the property, eg

```
class Foo {
    private static $Obj;

    private static getObj() {
        if (null === self::$Obj) {
            self::$Obj = (object) ['bizz', 'bazz'];
        }
        return self::$Obj;
    }
```

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing. to bad there isn't a way to do object literals.

Comment: Haven't used 5.4 yet, going to wait few more months, so this may be ignorant. But the `self::$Obj = (object) ['bizz', 'bazz'];` as written looks like it is trying to cast 'bizz' and 'bazz' as anon objects, which are assigned to self::$Obj, does that force self::$Obj to an array datatype, which contains both anon objects?

Comment: haha your right it would be problematic with that array but here is some info on it. http://www.webmaster-source.com/2009/08/20/php-stdclass-storing-data-object-instead-array/

Comment: @MikePurcell It's the equivalent of `(object) array('bizz', 'buzz')` which would produce a `stdclass` with two properties, `0` and `1` (I know, PHP lets you do some weird stuff)

Comment: @Phil: Gotcha, so it's assigning two attributes to the object, not trying to create two objects.