# Set an objects property equal to an instance of another object

Tags: php, parse-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Initializing PHP class property declarations with simple expressions yields syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702863/initializing-php-class-property-declarations-with-simple-expressions-yields-synt)

I dont want to have to instantiate my session object in every method.  Why cant I do this:

```
class Foo {

   public $session = Session::instance();

   public function bar() {
      // Pass success message in session
      $this->session('message', 'Success');

   }
}
```

The error I get:

```
[ Parse Error ]: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't allow you to use expressions in class definitions (which is standard in class definitions in many languages).  You can do a couple of things:

```
public function __construct() {
   $this->session = Session::instance();
}

//Dependency Injection
public function __construct(Session $session) {
   $this->session = $session;
}
```