# Assign global variable's value to class memeber

Tags: php, cakephp

Working in a CakePHP project and stucked at a place.

Config/bootstrap.php file

```
Configure::write('email_info', nehal@connectech.in);
```

Config/email.php {My custom email class}

```
class EmailConfig {
public $default = array(        
    'from' => Configure::read('email_info'),
    'reply' => Configure::read('email_info')    
);}
```

I know I can only assigned value of any variable which is outside the class using 'global' keyword, but how do I assign config variable to the value of array member?

Comment: Is something not working or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: you need to do this in the __construct method(), php only takes constant values when initializing attributes

Comment: Yes, The problem is I don't have constant value. I have values in configuration and that I want to assign to a class member. I am getting syntax error "Syntax error: unexpected: String expected: =>, ',', ';', )"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply initialize your property inside of the `__construct` method. PHP Only takes literals when initalizing properties.

```
class EmailConfig {
public $default = array(        
    'from' => Configure::read('email_info'),
    'reply' => Configure::read('email_info')    
);}


class EmailConfig {
  public function __construct() {   
     $this->default['from'] = Configure::read('email_info');
     $this->default['reply'] = Configure::read('email_info');
  }
}
```

For more info see this question: [Initializing PHP class property declarations with simple expressions yields syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702863/initializing-php-class-property-declarations-with-simple-expressions-yields-synt)

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but you can try this.

```
class EmailConfig {
  public $default = array(        
   'from' => ${Configure::read('email_info')},
   'reply' => ${Configure::read('email_info')}    
);}
```