# php constant in data member of a class

Tags: php, constants

What is wrong with below mentioned code? 
It is throwing parse error
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/gaurav/c.php on line 9

```
<?php

class b {
    const ABC = 'abc';
}

class c extends b {

    private $r = self::ABC ." d";
    function getABC()
    {
            echo $this->r;
    }
}

$c = new c();
$c->getABC();
```

Comment: What you want is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the cause for this error is that PHP does not allow expressions in class member declarations, even if only constant elements are used.

so `private $r = self::ABC ." d";` is not allowed, while `private $r = self::ABC;` is ok, as Gautam3164 answered.

more details for example in this answer:
[Initializing PHP class property declarations with simple expressions yields syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702863/initializing-php-class-property-declarations-with-simple-expressions-yields-synt)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
private $r = self::ABC;
$r = $r . "d";
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

```
This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.
```

So, in my code self::ABC ." d" is not constant.