# PHP unable to parse concatinated string in class

Tags: php, string, compiler-errors

I come across this strange behavior of PHP, assigning string:

```
class a {
    public $str = "a" . 'b';
}

$obj = new a();
echo $obj->str;
```

never works, throws following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/test.php on line 2

while using as plain PHP it works:

```
$str = "a" . 'b';
```

Comment: What's your question? I believe that's expected behaviour in PHP5 (all?) as you can't have expressions in property defaults?

Comment: Incidentally, this _does_ work in PHP 7.

Comment: This is valid from >= 5.6

Comment: @DarraghEnright You're right. I had to go back and check.

Comment: It is valid only if you use single quotes! The first string has double quotes: `"a"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initializing PHP class property declarations with simple expressions yields syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702863/initializing-php-class-property-declarations-with-simple-expressions-yields-synt)

Comment: @Riccardo I really don't think it's because of two different types of quotes. https://3v4l.org/d9mvs

Comment: @Don'tPanic Then is the PHP version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot perform complex assignment to variable before constructor, you can assign simple string or integer to a variable. dot is consider as function

if you have to assign them you should use constructor.

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Comment: In this case you don't need a constructor if the PHP version is >=5.6.0, this is the first documentation's  [example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#example-217)

Answer (score 0):

The dot . operator acts as a function and you cannot declare class variables using function.

If you have an init or construct function you should initialize the variable in such function.

```
function __construct() {
   $this->str = 'a' . 'b';
}
```

Comment: Then probably you're using php <5.6

Check phpinfo() to see what version of php you're using

Comment: In this case you don't need a constructor if the PHP version is >=5.6.0, this is the first documentation's [example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#example-217)

Comment: What PHP version are you using? Did you check phpinfo();? What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

Look the [documentation example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php#example-217).

Check your PHP version.

```php
class a {
    public $str = 'a' . 'b';
}
```